# Optimizing mysql query when using date range search

Tags: php, mysql

I have to date input boxes from date and to date for search data, currently im using 3 if statements for search . Is this correct way ? or is there any other best practices to use to take query time less . pls advice?

```
    if ((!empty($formData['from_date1'])) && (!empty($formData['to_date2']))) {
        $where_params .= "AND DATE(regdate) BETWEEN $from_date1 AND  $to_date2";
    } else if ((!empty($formData['from_date1'])) && (empty($formData['to_date2']))) {
        $where_params .= "AND DATE(regdate) >= $from_date1";
    } else if( (!empty($formData['to_date2'])) && (empty($formData['from_date1']))) {
        $where_params .= "AND DATE(regdate) <=  $to_date2";
    }
```

Comment: for conditional statements it's the right way for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix code with data while you not want create hole for sql injections.
You can move all logic into the query.
`... and (? is null or regdate >= ?) and (? is null or regdate <= ?)`
and send four additional parameters `[..., $from_date1, $from_date1, $to_date2, $to_date2]`